# Set Google Script variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Im trying to get the e-mail from the active user to put it in a Google Sheets but isn't working.

I created the function getEmail in .gs, but when I try to set it in a var, it doesn't happen:

Please, help me! :)

````
function getEmail() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
}

```.js code

var row = "";
row.push(google.script.run.getEmail());
````

Comment: Please, read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication), Google Apps Script communicates with client-side asynchoronously, so data is available only in context of success / failure handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Several remarks:

- You need to return `email` at the end of your `getEmail()` function
- `push()` is a method for arrays, you  can not apply it to a string. You need to either to define row as an array `var row=[]`, or, if it is not supposed to be an array, assign a value to it with the `=` operator instead of `push`.
- If you want to return to pass a value from an Apps Script function into the js code, you need to use [`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)).

> Please find below a working code snippet assigning the return value of
>   an Apps Script function to a Js variable:

.gs file

```
  function getEmail() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
    return email;
    }

function doGet(){
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  function onSuccess(email) {
        var row=email;
        console.log(row);
      }
var row=google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getEmail();  
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("enter id").getSheetByName("enter name");
  sheet.appendRow([Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);
}
```