# Tranfer data from a sheet to an html form

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking how **transfer data from a sheet to a dropdown in a form** using Google Script.

I've gathered the data in a table and I think the best solution for resolving this issue is to transfer the data through a JS script. (Tell me if you have a better option)

I did some tests following this link : [Set Google Script variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313500/set-google-script-variable-in-javascript)

Here's my code:

**Main.gs**

```
/**
 * Retrieves unique datas in a given column
 * @param column, the column where are the datas
 * @return uniqueDatas
 */
function searchUniqueDatas(column) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(5, column, sheetLastRow);
  var rangeData = range.getValues();
  var uniqueDatas = [];

  // Gather all the column datas
  for (var i=0; i < rangeData.length; i++) {
    uniqueDatas = uniqueDatas.concat(rangeData[i+1]);
  }
  return uniqueDatas = uniqueDatas.filter(onlyUnique);
}

var typeData = searchUniqueDatas(1); // The unique data are in a table. This works perfectly
```

**AddCustomer.GS**

```
// I tried to do as the link said
    function getData(data) {
      return data;
    }
    
    function doGet(){
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FormAddCsutomer');
    }
```

**AddCustomerForm.html**

```
  <label for="type">Type *</label><br/>
  <select multiple id="type" name="type" required>
    <!-- dropdown to fill -->
  </select><br/><br/>
```

Hope I made myself clear.

***Edit after Cooper answer***

I did some tests following your code. Still not working though.

Could you help me to find what's wrong ?

**Google Script**

```
// getData(data) and doGet() have been deleted
function getSelectOptions()
{
  sortOptions();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0; i < typeData.getValues().length; i++)
  {
    options.push(typeData.getValues()[i][0]);
  }
  return typeData.getValues();
}
```

**HTML**

```
      <label for="type">Type</label><br/>
      <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="" selected></option>
      </select><br/><br/>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#txt1').val('');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();
      });

    function updateSelect(vA) {
      var select = document.getElementById("type");
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0; i < vA.length; i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
      }
    }
    </script>
```

NEW EDIT

@Cooper: Following your table example,

**.gs**

```
function getUniqueCustomers () {
  return customerData.getValues(); // Return a 1-dimension table with the data
}
```

**.html**

```
<form id="filterForm" onSubmit="handleFormSubmitFilter(this)">

      <label for="customer">Customer</label><br/>
      <select name="customer" id="customer">
        <? var vs = getUniqueCustomers();
          for (var i=0; i < vs.length; i++) { ?>
          <option> <?= vs[i]  ?> </option>
        <?
         }
        ?>
      </select><br/><br/>
    ...
</form>
```

I tried with a for and a forEach. It once displays "" and not the data.

I wonder if the code between  is recognized.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT 6th August,**

Still trying to resolving this issue.

I tried to follow this tuto video but I don't manage to adapt my code (I have only one column in my sheet and I would like that the text, value and id are the same data for each option).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmQdrAIdfGM

Here's my code.
Thanks for the help.

```
// Return a simple array with all the sheet values. It works
function getUniqueCustomers () {
  return customerData.getValues();
}
```

HTML

```
      <label for="customer">Customer</label><br/>
      <select name="customer" id="customer" onChange="onSelectCustomer()">
      <script>loadCustomer();</script>
      </select><br/><br/>

<script>
function loadCustomer() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
    var customerSelect = document.getById('customer');

    let option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    customerSelect.appendChild(option);

    ar.forEach(function (item) {
      option.value = item[0];
      option.text = item[0];
      option.id = item[0];
      customerSelect.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).getList();
};

function onSelectCustomer() {
  var id = document.getElementById("customer").value;
  document.getElementById("carValue").innerHTML = id;
};
</script>
```

Comment: typeData and sortOptions() is undefined.

Comment: getSelectOptions() should be called from window.onload or $(function)  if using JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the action from the html form

You can use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( data => {//display data here}).getData()`

Here's another example of writing data to a dialog.

GS:

```
function getMySheetData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  return vs;
}

function launchMyTableDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1').evaluate().setWidth(800),'Title');
}
```

html:(filename: ah1.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>My Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = getMySheetData(); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
```

My Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 5 | 18 | 13 | 6 | 8 | 17 | 13 | 4 | 11 |
| 13 | 19 | 13 | 6 | 15 | 4 | 19 | 11 | 7 | 18 |
| 5 | 11 | 7 | 17 | 7 | 14 | 9 | 12 | 11 | 6 |
| 13 | 5 | 3 | 14 | 6 | 11 | 15 | 7 | 3 | 14 |
| 11 | 2 | 11 | 17 | 5 | 15 | 18 | 16 | 6 | 16 |
| 16 | 12 | 7 | 13 | 10 | 3 | 6 | 18 | 14 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 15 | 0 | 2 | 15 | 9 | 4 | 2 | 18 |
| 1 | 6 | 12 | 15 | 2 | 17 | 11 | 13 | 14 | 16 |
| 11 | 1 | 7 | 4 | 17 | 12 | 0 | 5 | 12 | 19 |
| 6 | 1 | 8 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 15 | 18 | 7 | 2 |
| 18 | 2 | 0 | 16 | 4 | 19 | 12 | 2 | 16 | 15 |
| 19 | 11 | 6 | 16 | 10 | 3 | 15 | 8 | 4 | 16 |
| 14 | 14 | 14 | 17 | 15 | 3 | 8 | 2 | 6 | 9 |
| 13 | 14 | 10 | 12 | 15 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 9 | 5 |
| 1 | 0 | 13 | 19 | 10 | 19 | 5 | 11 | 9 | 12 |
| 1 | 10 | 19 | 18 | 4 | 4 | 8 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 18 | 12 | 9 | 15 | 18 | 5 | 5 | 19 | 9 | 1 |
| 19 | 6 | 11 | 0 | 8 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 9 | 10 |
| 12 | 11 | 1 | 2 | 7 | 1 | 11 | 3 | 12 | 0 |
| 14 | 18 | 13 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 11 | 18 | 7 | 2 |

The Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you explain me how does this line work ? How can I insert it in the dropdown as options ?

Comment: Hi,
I edited my topic cause I couldn't post the answer in the comment section. I ping you in case you didn't see it.
 Thanks :)

Comment: Hello,
Any suggestions before this topic is forgotten